# How to Use LibXtract with iOS project?

Tags: ios, c, audio, mfcc

I am trying to extract some features from audio files, MFCC to be accurate. Then I found a C library LibXtract, that would do the job for me.

I am trying to use LibXtract in iOS project, I have followed this tutorial

http://inote.apptrek.net/2011/10/howto-compile-native-c-codes-to-a-library-for-ios-development-in-xcode-take-mosquitto-for-an-example/

but I got some problems in process, first I got this warning

ld: warning: ignoring file ......./libLibXtract.a, missing required architecture i386 in file ..../libLibXtract.a

and those errors

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_xtract_asdf", referenced from:
      -[VoiceRecAppDelegate applicationWillResignActive:] in VoiceRecAppDelegate.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

So I would like to ask for your help in this problem, I would like to extract the MFCC from scratch with only obj-C code if possible.

Regards,
Omar

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to build your application with the *Simulator* as a target, but the LibXtract static library was *not built for the i386 architecture*.

You can confirm this with:

```
lipo -info /path/to/libxtract.a
```

The result from `lipo` should list the i386 architecture.

If it doesn't, then check that iphonesimulator is included in the Supported Platforms build setting in your LibXtract Xcode project and that i386 is included in the list of architectures.

It is also possible to compile autotools-based libraries for iOS/Simulator from the command line. Some instructions for this can be found [here](http://www.galloway.me.uk/2009/11/compiling-static-libraries-for-iphone-simulator/). Note: these are a little out-of-date so some of the options may need tweaking, although the principle remains the same.

**However, it is far simpler to compile LibXtract into your application by dragging the LibXtract sources into your application's Xcode project!**

I generally tend to have a "Libraries" group in my projects, under which I place third party sources (like LibXtract), as follows:

[image: LibXtract Source Tree]

When dragging the files into your project ensure that you check the checkbox for your application in "Add to targets".

[image]

The LibXtract sources will then be compiled into your application and you can remove libxtract.a from your linker settings (or frameworks).